# Linking SSIS packages to a table to all me to control which packages should run

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, package, data-warehouse

I am a newbie to SSIS and trying to replicate the current ELT process (which is configured via a set of store procedures) using SSIS.

The ELT process:
I have a config table that has all the table information stored.
The key column in this table is called 'Active'. This allows me to enable and deactivate tables that I don't want the ELT to run at any given time.
The ELT_SP scans the DWH_Process table for tables marked as active and thereafter executes the schedule for that specific job via server agent.

The SSIS Process
I have configured the SSIS packages to extract data from the CRMs and import into DWH.
I have used the 'sequence containers' control flow to replicate the ELT process, and this is working perfectly.

The problem is, I would then have to update 300+ tables and redeploy to the DWH.

In SSIS, what other options are available to me, and is there a simpler way to add in the 'check active status' before executing the package through a job agent?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A setup I've used in the past is something like this:
[image: Concept]

1. Setup a table with the configuration, something with columns like PackageName, IsEnabled, Partition ...
2. Create a loop package, that you are going to call in the root packages. The loop package queries, the config table based on a parameter of the package (e.g. Partition=1) , for a specific partition. The query also filters on IsEnabled = 1 or a different condition for your case. After the query you starts a foreach loop for every result/package that's returned from the query. This foreach then calls the actual package with your logic. You use a variable from the foreach to start the `Execute package task`
   [image: Loop packages]
3. Create a root package
4. In a sequence container in the root package, add N execute package tasks that calls the loop package, where you pass a parameter which partition they are executing. (This is purely for performance to run multiple packages at once.)
   [image: Sequence container with execute package tasks]

The benefit of this approach is you can enabled disable packages with a simple update statement, no need to redeploy. You can play with the partitions to get the best performance.

Comment: Thank you, I have used a similar flow and was able to create the Process table.

Comment: Consider upvoting the answer and accepting the answer if it solves your problem